# How to cancel a task using using cancel(true) in Java?

Tags: java, java-threads

I have two classes:

```
class C1 implements Callable<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        return true;
    }
}

class C2 implements Callable<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And I'm using this code:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Future<Boolean> c1 = es.submit(new C1());
Future<Boolean> c2 = es.submit(new C2());
if (c2.get()) {
    c1.cancel(true);
}
System.out.println(c1.isCancelled());
es.shutdown();
```

Which produces the expected result:

```
false
```

As per my understanding `c1.cancel(true);` return false, since the task was already completed. What should I do in order to be able to create an operation in which the task can be canceled? Maybe put the thread somehow to sleep? I need this result:

```
true
```

Comment: `c1` is finishing before you cancel it.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ok, and how can I do something so it doesn't not finish before cancel() it? I need to have a `true` result in the console.

Comment: Do something that a) takes a long time, b) is interruptible. For example, `Thread.sleep(/* some large number of milliseconds */);`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Where should I add that?

Comment: @AndyTurner Any idea please? Thanks

Comment: Inside the thing you want to cancel.

Comment: @AndyTurner I tried adding `Thread.sleep(1_000);` inside C1 class, right before `return true;` and I get the same result. Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to interrupt your `Callable` task using `Future.cancel(true)`, then you have to write your task such a way that it is responsive to the interruption. Inside the while loop you can check for the interrupt status, if it is not interrupted you can call `Thread.sleep` with some timeout. Also note that the `Thread.sleep` is a blocking interruptible method, which throws an `java.lang.InterruptedException` when the thread is interrupted while sleeping. Here's how it looks.

```
class C1 implements Callable<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here's your client program.

```
final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
final Future<Boolean> c1 = es.submit(new C1());
final boolean cancelled = c1.cancel(true);
System.out.println(cancelled);
es.shutdown();
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for answering. I still need this `if (c2.get()) {
    c1.cancel(true);
}` If I keep this condition, the app hangs. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, `Future.get` is a blocking call which waits until the task is completed. However, the task never gets completed in this case, hence your main thread blocks indefinitely.